# How to compare date derived from Excel date picker to a date from the =TODAY() function?

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting, compare

In Excel 2010, I require a date input using the 'Date and Time Picker' tool to be compared to a date derived from the =TODAY() function. If the two dates are the same I add that event to the calendar.

The date from the Date and Time Picker's (DTP) linked cell feature is in a different format to the =TODAY() date and thus always return false when compared.

If you double click the DTP date so the cell goes into edit mode and then un-select the cell, that date then becomes the correct format and now can be compared to the =TODAY() date.

This could be seen when I started playing around with the cell formats. Normally if you change the format of a date from 'Date' to 'Number' it converts that date into a raw five digit number of around 43,###, however before being double clicked the DTP date remains as a date but changes to a number after being double clicked.

I have tried messing around with the cell formatting for both types of date, making them 'date', 'text', 'number', etc. How do I solve without having to manually double click every date?

Comment: If both are in cells then you can try to compare `DatePickerCell.Value2 = FunctionCell.Value2` and see if it helps.

Comment: What that means is that the date is being returned from the tool as text.  one would need to adjust the code to return a double.

Comment: Hey Scott, I have gone into the code for the DTP and changed the "ByVal CallbackField As String" to "### As Double" however this is now giving my a compile error saying 'Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name'. I'm not really sure exactly what this mean, do you have any further suggestions/was this even the right bit to try and alter?

Comment: you would need to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the result to a date using the cDate function.